# Win32::Job spawn error with use strict

Tags: perl

The following:

```
  $job->spawn($Config{$console_path},  $command, new_group);
```

Spawns the new process. The following:

```
 $job->spawn($command, new_group);
```

Does not, even though %config does not exist.

Comment: `my $job->spawn` doesn't make any sense. What are you trying to do? Some more context around the code you're having trouble with would help.

Comment: No you haven't. How could you, when the expression `my $job` ensures that `$job` is undefined? Show some context or nobody's going to be able to understand what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably use it like this instead:

```
$job = Win32::Job->new;
$job->spawn($CAD_command, new_group);
```

Using `use strict` in your code is generally good practice.